# dotnet can't find my SDL instalation (C#, macOS)

Tags: c#, .net, homebrew, sdl-2

I'm creating a project with dotnet, SDL2 (installed with **brew**), and C#.

I got a basic code that initializes and creates a window, but when I try to run the project with `dotnet run` I got the next error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'SDL2' or one of its dependencies. 
In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: 
dlopen(libSDL2, 0x0001): tried: 'libSDL2' (no such file),
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibSDL2' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libSDL2' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libSDL2'
(no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libSDL2' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libSDL2' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

Seems obvious that dotnet can't find the SDL2 install folder, I have a walkaround making a copy from the brew folder to my working directory:

```
cp /opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2/lib/libSDL2.dylib libSDL2.dylib
```

After copying the file the SDL2 window shows up and works normally as intended.

How do I configure dotnet to search also on the `/opt/homebrew/opt/` folder?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing#unmanaged-native-library-probing